# version compare function, about special character

Tags: erlang, rabbitmq

I am studying rabbitmq source code now for learning erlang technique.

The following is from `rabbit_misc.erl` file. The purpose is to check application's minimum version. 
In the 5th and 7th sub sentance of `version_compare/N`, there is is a special character, which is `$0`. But I don't know how it happens?
My reason that it will not happens is that in the last sentance, after lists:splitwith/N, `AT1` and `BT1` will be started with `"$."`.

```
version_compare(A, B, lte) ->
    case version_compare(A, B) of
        eq -> true;
        lt -> true;
        gt -> false
    end;
version_compare(A, B, gte) ->
    case version_compare(A, B) of
        eq -> true;
        gt -> true;
        lt -> false
    end;
version_compare(A, B, Result) ->
    Result =:= version_compare(A, B).

version_compare(A, A) ->
    eq;
version_compare([], [$0 | B]) ->
    version_compare([], dropdot(B));
version_compare([], _) ->
    lt; %% 2.3 < 2.3.1
version_compare([$0 | A], []) ->
    version_compare(dropdot(A), []);
version_compare(_, []) ->
    gt; %% 2.3.1 > 2.3
version_compare(A,  B) ->
    {AStr, ATl} = lists:splitwith(fun (X) -> X =/= $. end, A),
    {BStr, BTl} = lists:splitwith(fun (X) -> X =/= $. end, B),
    ANum = list_to_integer(AStr),
    BNum = list_to_integer(BStr),
    if ANum =:= BNum -> version_compare(dropdot(ATl), dropdot(BTl));
       ANum < BNum   -> lt;
       ANum > BNum   -> gt
    end.
```

Answer (score 0):

$0 is not a special character -- this is zero string: "0".

Versions may be complex: 0.1.22.333 and splitwith/2 splits into head and tail ("0" and ".1.22.333").

I imagine that handling $0 is for cases like "1.0.0" and "1"

```
{"1",".0.0"} vs {"1",[]}
```

Comment: Or rather it is the Latin1 value of the character `0`, 48. The `$c` is syntactic sugar for the Latin1 (and unicode) value of the character.